# Encoding mssql data using vb.net function

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, encoding, character-encoding

I have migrated mysql database to mssql 2008 using Microsoft SQL server migration assistant but am still facing problem with encoding.

Is there a way to read each row and convert the unicode to UTF-8 or windows-1252 ?

am using the following function :

```
Private Function GetDataWithArabic(ByVal srcData As String) As String
    Dim iso As Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")
    Dim unicode As Encoding = Encoding.[Default]
    Dim unicodeBytes As Byte() = iso.GetBytes(srcData)
    Return unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes)
End Function
```

The data looks like below and it suppose to show Arabic text :

> ÇáãÌäÏÉ ÇáÅÓÑÇÆíáíÉ: ÓÃÓÊãÊÚ ÈÞÊá ÇáÚÑÈ æÐÈÍåã

Below is the snap from the original mysql database to know to encoding :

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `6rp2_on`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `6rp2_on` (
  `session` char(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `6rp2_on`

LOCK TABLES `6rp2_on` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `6rp2_on` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `6rp2_on` VALUES ('',1381695068);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `6rp2_on` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft SQL Server is reading the data differently. You have to check what type of data format MS SQL server uses, especially with Arabic, and then make sure the data you want to transfer is in that format before you transfer. Check this article for more info:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/04/29/converting-from-mysql-to-sql-server-working-with-data-types.aspx

Go to this section:

Using Charset Mapping to Control the Conversion of MySQL `VARCHAR` to SQL Server `VARCHAR`/`NVARCHAR`

Comment: where is the article link ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2011/04/29/converting-from-mysql-to-sql-server-working-with-data-types.aspx